# How do I find my MacBook Pro password?

Tags: macbook-pro, password

I have a new MacBook Pro 2017, running OS 10.13.6 and I am afraid to shut down because I don't remember my password.  How do I find it or make a new one?

Comment: Also, don’t feel that a closed question is bad. It’s good since it links all the similar posts to one where the best answers can live.

Comment: try something simple, like changing the clock or date/time, there you can try to unlock with the password you believe is the right one without consequences.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple methods to reset an admin password. Once you restart, Apple guides you to this when you fail to enter the password correctly.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860

Also these questions cover the ground pretty thoroughly.

- [Lost access to admin user account in my mac book pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328192/lost-access-to-admin-user-account-in-my-mac-book-pro)
- [How can I get admin access to a Mac without knowing the current password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password)
- [How to hack into a deceased person's Mac that is still running?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238213/how-to-hack-into-a-deceased-persons-mac-that-is-still-running)